# Grinding when shifting into gear (new clutch)

Tags: transmission, clutch, manual-transmission

I was thinking of buying a car but it ALWAYS grinds when shifting into 4th gear (up or down) regardless of the rpm.  It occasionally grinds when shifting into 5th and 6th (only up) at a higher rpm.  The owner told me that he just put in a new clutch (did it himself).  I did notice that the clutch pedal was stiffer than I am used to.

Is this a result of the new clutch with a bad adjustment, or are the synchros bad? I didn't know about the double clutching test until after I looked at the car.  He lives a pretty far drive away to test this again.

Does this have serious repercussions if ignored?

Comment: If you've not bought the car, walk away. A new clutch wouldn't cause this.

Comment: I haven't bought the car.  Even if it is an expensive repair I would like to know the answers for personal knowledge.  The cost of the car was cheap enough where it might still be worth a full transmission rebuild.

Comment: I'd suggest there's an issue with the transmission (internally), but you won't know until you pull the tranny apart. Be prepared to completely replace the transmission.

Comment: You should put your two comments in an answer so I can upvote you.  Those answer my questions enough.

Comment: if the grinding (sound) occurs when the gear is shifted after the clutch is fully depressed (and before re-engaging it) , then it's a sign of worn out synchros.

Answer (score 2):

If you've not bought the car, walk away. A new clutch wouldn't cause this.

I'd suggest there's an issue with the transmission (internally), but you won't know until you pull the tranny apart. Be prepared to completely replace the transmission.